# VLC made it impossible to install or delete

Tags: vlc

this is what it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rpm : Depends: librpm2 (>= 4.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: librpmbuild2 (>= 4.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: librpmio2 (>= 4.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: librpmsign0 (>= 4.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: rpm2cpio but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: rpm-common (= 4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-nox : Depends: libvlc5 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I type the `apt-get -f` install this is what I get next

```
bilal@bilal-Aspire-8930:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for bilal: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for bilal: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libvlc5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvlc5
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/50.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 147 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Sub-process gzip returned an error code (1)
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlc5_2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 171161 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libvlc5 (from .../libvlc5_2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): failed to read on buffer copy for failed to write to pipe in copy: Input/output error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlc5_2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlc5_2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
bilal@bilal-Aspire-8930:~$
```

Comment: it mad eit impossible to instal other programs or delete them , and vlc itsel is not working

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the .deb files is actually corrupted. Do the following:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -f install
```